# Can't move img in display block?

Tags: html, css, image, center

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="mitte"><a href="http://www.web.com"><img id="img_mittig" src="tienda.png" /></a></div>
```

And this my css:

```
#img_mittig{ display: block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
```

The `img` is center right, but when I try, for example, to move down the image with `top: 200px;`, it doesn't work. Why ?

Comment: Can you put it in a JSFiddle? I think the problem is in some other CSS code

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/SoSoDef/4twL6/; Thanks

Comment: The `top` declaration does nothing unless you specify `position` to `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `position` on your element to be able to use `top`.
So for example:

```
#img_mittig { position: relative; top: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`top:200px` will only work with `position:absolute` or `position:relative;` or `position:fixed`

what you are trying to achieve can be achieved using `margin-top:200px;`

Comment: Or `position: fixed` (pretty much *any* value other than the default of `static`, in fact).

Answer (score 1):

You cant move block element with no positioning with "top, left, right, bottom". Use margins and paddings. For example `margin-top: 200px;`
If you want move img by setting `top: 200px` then set `position: relative` for img.